# How to get data attribute value for selected option?

Tags: javascript, html

When I selected he just get value name `Ahmad` - how can I get the value `ahmad zakaria`?

HTML:

```
<select name="kd_produk" id="family">
    <option value="one"
    data-name= "Ahmad Zakaria"
    data-wife= "My wife">number one</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$("select#family").change(function(){
var name1 = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('name1');
var wife1 = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('wife1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute `wife1` or `name1` in your markup for the select element's `<option />`.

Try removing `1` from each key string that you're passing to the `.data()` method:

```
var name = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('name');
var wife = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('wife');
```

This will ensure the values corresponding to the attrbiutes `data-wife` and `data-name` are retrieved as expected:

```js
var name = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('name');
var wife = $('select#family').find(':selected').data('wife');

console.log('data-name of selected:', name)
console.log('data-wife of selected:', wife)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="kd_produk" id="family">
    <option value="one"
    data-name= "Ahmad Zakaria"
    data-wife= "My wife">number one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this not working for me, but I have found a solution, 
`<option value='one'   data-name1= '{"name": "Ahmad Zakaria","wife":"My wife"}'></option>
alert($(this).find(":selected").data("name1").name);`
Thank you for the help